# Generics constraint doesn't appear to work in C#

Tags: c#, generics

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Manager<T>' to `Manager<Asset>'
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the above compile-time error with the code below. Since the T type associated with Manager must derive from Asset, shouldn't it work?

```
public class Manager<T> where T : Asset
{
    public Manager()
    {
        var t = new Test();
        t.Manager = this; //compile-time error
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Manager<Asset> Manager;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the T type associated with Manager must derive from Asset, shouldn't it work?

No, because the type parameter in generic classes [is not covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That is, if you have `DerivedAsset : Asset`, then you are not allowed to assign `Manager<Asset> manager = new Manager<DerivedAsset>()`.

You can make a type parameter covariant by using `out T`, but this is only possible for interfaces.  So you would need this:

```
public interface IManager<out T> where T : Asset { }

public class Test
{
    public IManager<Asset> Manager;
}
```

Now you should be able to write your original code, making `Manager<T>` implement `IManager<T>`:

```
public class Manager<T> : IManager<T> 
    where T : Asset
{
    public Manager()
    {
        var t = new Test();
        t.Manager = this;     // ok, because T in IManager<T> is covariant
    }
}
```

(As @sjkm noted, you could also simply do a cast: `t.Manager = (Manager<Asset>)this;`.  But this would only work if you are sure that the `T` in `Manager<T>` is never a derived class -- if `Asset` were sealed, for example.)

Comment: That won't work; a `Manager<T>` is not a `Manager<Asset>`, unless `T` is `Asset`

Comment: "The type parameter in generic classes is not covariant by default": actually it's never covariant, not just by default. Variance only applies to interfaces and delegates, not classes

Comment: @user2800679 the cast won't work if you have a `Manager<DerivedAsset>`.  And no, it won't help if `Asset` is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a `T` is an `Asset` doesn't mean that a `Manager<T>` is a `Manager<Asset>`. It would work if `Manager<T>` was covariant in `T`, but classes can't be covariant in C# (only interfaces and delegates can).

Instead, you can make `Test` generic as well:

```
public class Test<T> where T : Asset
{
    public Manager<T> Manager;
}
```

And it should now work as expected.